# google api key stop working suddenly, what is standard process to generate google api key?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-api-2

My code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY"></script>
```

I dont know why google map api key stop working in between, why this is happening, may i know standard procedure to create google api key?

Comment: Try logging onto the developer console - https://console.developers.google.com/ ~ once logged in you can view credentials and regenerate api key

Comment: error_message "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API."
results 
status "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"

Comment: Do you execute any client side service (geocoding, places, directions etc.)? If so, you should be aware that there is per session limit. If you send too many requests they will be blocked: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#UsageLimits